# Caddy hard-coded localhost:8080 collides with existing services, also AutoSSL collides w/443

Tags: rocket.chat

I installed Rocket.Chat on my Ubuntu system with SNAP, which in itself seems to work so far ... anyway, I have problems with collisions in the ports used.
For one, caddy seems to be started with localhost:8080 binding, even though I updated the Caddyfile ...

[..]
   CGroup: /system.slice/snap.rocketchat-server.rocketchat-caddy.service
           `-3360 caddy -conf=/var/snap/rocketchat-server/1172/Caddyfile -host=localhost:8080
[..]

How can I alter this?

Also, when attempting to use the AutoSSL feature, again I have a collision, as the program seems to want to bind to *:443 instead of a specific IP ... where/how can I change that?

Thanks!

Comment: To keep things simple, I decided to just forego the Caddy setup and just use the existing Apache as reverse proxy ... works fine both unencrypted and with the multi-domain LetsEncrypt certificate ...